# Find a scaling transform of a function

Tags: r, estimation, matlab

Let us consider some function $f(x)$ (that is similar to sum of many separate gaussian peaks) and a function $F(x)=Cf(s(x)) + b(x)$. We know the values of $f(x)$ at points ${x_i}, (i=1,...,N)$ and values of $F(x)$ at points $\{x_j\},(j=1,...,M)$ (where $N$ and $M$ are big enough). From some considerations we model $s(x)$ and $b(x)$ as a low degree polynomial, for example $s(x) = s_0+s_1x$ and $b(x) = b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2$.
How I can try to estimate the coefficients $C$, $s_k (k=0,1)$, $b_p (p=0,1,2)$?

Is there a simple way to implement this in R or in MatLab?

Comment: This sounds similar to [dynamic time warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping)